# Weren't+subject ... and Were+subject+not ... are they both correct for inverted conditionals?

Tags: inversion, negative-inversion

I've seen many examples that suggest putting **not** after the **subject**. E.g.

> Were Elsa **not** a brave girl, she wouldn't go with us.

Can we write:

> Weren't Elsa a brave girl, she wouldn't go with us.

as if we invert the subject and the verb in an interrogative sentence?

The reason I'm asking this problem is, there's an interactive game in this [website](https://www.clarkandmiller.com/inverted-conditionals-have-you-mastered-this-advanced-english-trick/).

The quiz is:

> If we weren't so clever, we wouldn't have got the contract.

When I write:

> Weren't we so clever, we wouldn't have got the contract.

It marked my answer as incorrect. The correct answer is

> Were we not so clever, we wouldn't have got the contract.

Like the experience I had before, I don't trust an interactive program, since there's a possibility the answer has more than one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the program is correct

> Can we write:
> Weren't Elsa a brave girl, she wouldn't go with us.

No. That is non-standard

> Weren't we so clever, we wouldn't have got the contract.

Again, this is non-standard